# Odd crash on app happening when I build from my machine, however doesn't crash from another person's machine

Tags: android, crash, unity-game-engine

So whenever I build the app from my machine, the app crashes on a scene change. If we build from another person's machine it runs fine. Checked all unity publish settings and sdk settings are set the same on both machines (as far as we can tell) Any ideas?

Here is the log cat error.

```
04-28 06:30:08.420: A/libc(9867): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x05671024 (code=1)
04-28 06:30:08.950: I/DEBUG(4666): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-28 06:30:08.950: I/DEBUG(4666): Build fingerprint: 'Android/full_m805_892x/m805_892x:4.0.4/IMM76D/eng.watt.20121011.195340:eng/test-keys'
04-28 06:30:08.960: I/DEBUG(4666): pid: 9867, tid: 9883  >>> com.vinci.wordproblem <<<
04-28 06:30:08.960: I/DEBUG(4666): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 05671024
04-28 06:30:08.960: I/DEBUG(4666):  r0 01926370  r1 017a9c74  r2 00000000  r3 05671024
04-28 06:30:08.960: I/DEBUG(4666):  r4 017a9c74  r5 02b38814  r6 017a9c74  r7 66447970
04-28 06:30:08.960: I/DEBUG(4666):  r8 6644798c  r9 658f77f8  10 00000000  fp 00000000
04-28 06:30:08.970: I/DEBUG(4666):  ip 00000000  sp 66447424  lr 658f6b14  pc 658eaaa4  cpsr 20000010
04-28 06:30:08.970: I/DEBUG(4666):  d0  0000000000000000  d1  3f80000000000000
04-28 06:30:08.970: I/DEBUG(4666):  d2  000000003f800000  d3  c12017ea3f800000
04-28 06:30:08.970: I/DEBUG(4666):  d4  8000000000000000  d5  0000000080000000
04-28 06:30:08.970: I/DEBUG(4666):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
04-28 06:30:08.970: I/DEBUG(4666):  d8  000000003eaaaaab  d9  0000000000000000
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d16 3fc061203221a32b  d17 3fe5b4e35529eeba
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d18 bf29ce48f96338c0  d19 3ec6cd878c3b46a7
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d20 3fda84060f1fd496  d21 3fd3c46551448a03
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d22 3e21ee0f9f5d0f55  d23 bda8fae9be8838d4
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d24 000000003f800000  d25 0000000000000000
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d26 3f80000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 000000003f800000
04-28 06:30:08.980: I/DEBUG(4666):  d30 00000000bf555556  d31 3f80000000000000
04-28 06:30:09.000: I/DEBUG(4666):  scr 6000009b
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666):          #00  pc 004a8aa4  /data/data/com.vinci.wordproblem/lib/libunity.so (_ZNK8Animator16IsMatchingTargetEv)
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666):          #01  pc 004b4b10  /data/data/com.vinci.wordproblem/lib/libunity.so (_ZN8Animator11TargetMatchEb)
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): code around pc:
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): 658eaa84 e5831008 e0814004 e791118c e0841001  .....@..........
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): 658eaa94 e5841004 e5923004 e5912018 e0853003  .....0... ...0..
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): 658eaaa4 e7931182 e0833182 e0832001 e5832004  .....1... ... ..
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): 658eaab4 edd07a40 eef57ac0 eef1fa10 ba000009  @z...z..........
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): 658eaac4 e5903104 e5921030 e1530001 03a00001  .1..0.....S.....
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): code around lr:
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): 658f6af4 e3530000 e24dd00c e1a06001 0a000204  ..S...M..`......
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): 658f6b04 e590305c e3530000 0a000201 ebffcfbe  \0....S.........
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): 658f6b14 e3500000 0a0001fe e5951050 e28d9f5e  ..P.....P...^...
04-28 06:30:09.470: I/DEBUG(4666): 658f6b24 e1a00009 e28d7f52 e2811010 e28d4f46  ....R.......FO..
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666): 658f6b34 ebffce5a e5953044 e595104c e1a00007  Z...D0..L.......
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666): memory map around addr 05671024:
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666): 00c74000-03402000 [heap]
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666): (no map for address)
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666): 10000000-10001000 
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666): stack:
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666):     664473e4  3b5c469b  
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666):     664473e8  3aec82f4  
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666):     664473ec  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666):     664473f0  39a29201  
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666):     664473f4  bb929e01  
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666):     664473f8  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666):     664473fc  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.480: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447400  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.490: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447404  3f800000  
04-28 06:30:09.490: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447408  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.490: I/DEBUG(4666):     6644740c  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.490: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447410  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.490: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447414  3f800000  
04-28 06:30:09.500: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447418  df0027ad  
04-28 06:30:09.500: I/DEBUG(4666):     6644741c  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.500: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447420  017a9f90  [heap]
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666): #00 66447424  01926370  [heap]
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447428  01926370  [heap]
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666):     6644742c  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666): #01 66447430  66447578  
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447434  66447548  
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447438  3f800000  
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666):     6644743c  3f800000  
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447440  3f800000  
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447444  3f800000  
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447448  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666):     6644744c  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.510: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447450  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.520: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447454  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.520: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447458  3f800000  
04-28 06:30:09.520: I/DEBUG(4666):     6644745c  3f800000  
04-28 06:30:09.520: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447460  3f800000  
04-28 06:30:09.520: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447464  3f800000  
04-28 06:30:09.530: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447468  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.530: I/DEBUG(4666):     6644746c  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.530: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447470  00000000  
04-28 06:30:09.530: I/DEBUG(4666):     66447474  00000000  
04-28 06:30:18.690: I/BootReceiver(1066): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
04-28 06:30:18.990: I/ActivityManager(1066): Process com.vinci.wordproblem (pid 9867) has died.
04-28 06:30:18.990: I/WindowManager(1066): WIN DEATH: Window{4161ca58 SurfaceView paused=false}
04-28 06:30:19.070: W/ActivityManager(1066): Force removing ActivityRecord{4133e8f0 com.vinci.wordproblem/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}: app died, no saved state
04-28 06:30:19.100: W/InputDispatcher(1066): channel '415d8ed8 com.vinci.wordproblem/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
04-28 06:30:19.100: E/InputDispatcher(1066): channel '415d8ed8 com.vinci.wordproblem/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: 1 update to this, I updated my android sdk installs, and was able to produce a stable build. I would like to note however that when this issue happened in the past, updating my sdk didn't help.

Comment: another update. Today I again can't produce a build that doesn't crash. Same Error. Haven't changed anything except an audio file update.